# Spring Boot : Integration Test not excluding my Application configuration class

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an application which connects to a zookeeper to perform operations on HBase. However, for Integration Tests, I have a class to create in-memory tables, and perform tests without trying to connect to said zookeeper.

I have defined a IntegrationTestAppConfig.class as follows:

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { AppConfig.class})
@ComponentScan
@Configuration
@EnableAsync
public class IntegrationTestAppConfig{
    ..... //this is where I create a bean for my HBaseConnectionManager to use my in-memory table environment
 }
```

And, in my integration test class, I have the following:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringApplicationConfiguration(classes = IntegrationTestAppConfig.class)
public class AHCLIManagerIT {
    @Test
      .....
 }
```

Based on what I've read from the Spring-boot documentation, the integration test class should use IntegrationTestAppConfig.class for the application configuration.

However, when I run the Integration Test, I get an error saying connection to zookeeper timed out. In the stack trace, I see that the error occurred in AppConfig.java (my main class for app configuration), where it tries to create a HBaseConnection to the zookeeper.

I don't understand why my application is not using the App config class that I've defined in the annotations.

Comment: The IT settings probably uses `IntegrationTestAppConfig`. Also, `exclude = { AppConfig.class}` excludes the class from auto configuring beans. However because of  `@ComponentScan`, `AppConfig` configuration class is still scanned. You should use a Profile or Conditional mechanism to distinguish between your two beans.

Answer (score 1):

Is your AopConfig class actually an autoconfiguration class? Autoconfiguration classes are loaded by naming them in a spring.factories file in META-INF. The exclude attribute would only apply to those I believe. Auto configuration happens after regular app configuration anyways.

Also you have `@ComponentScan` on your config. If you really need to exclude AopConfig that would be the annotation I'd expect it to be on.

Though IMHO something doesn't seem right for doing a component scan in your tests